# Generating Glossaries again without deleting the old ones

Tags: glossaries

I am generating my glossaries (perl installed) with

```
makeglossaries
```

and they are all created and shown in my pdf when I create them the first time.

Over the time my glossaries change and new ones are added etc. 
But when I call make glossaries again they aren't updated. Regardless on how many times a call the command.

The only way to "refresh" them is to delete all temporary files from the tex-compilation and compile everything again.

But that can't be right, right? :)

Hopefully somebody can help me.

Grettings Lukas

---

Edit: Thanks so far!

I do all the recompiling before and after "makeglossaries".

In addition I experience the following:

- Only existing glossaries aren't changing after e.g. I fixed a typo in
  the description or want to have another \first occurence.
- Completely new entries are added after the whole recompiling/makeglossaries
  process and shown as they should.

Her is my MWE including (hopefully) all relevant information:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
%[...] other packages, commands, etc.
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[toc, nonumberlist, acronym, translate=babel]{glossaries} 
\begin{document}
\listoftables
\listoffigures
\tableofcontents
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]
%[...] includes, etc. ...
\input{Inhalt/glossaries}
\printglossary[type=main] 
\glsresetall
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\IfFileExists{\jobname.glo}` is where I'd start.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! That is certainly not how it works for me (and I don't do anything special to check file existence or whatever). However, without a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem, it is hard to say what the problem might be. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Afterthought: you do recompile before rerunning `makeglossaries` and then recompile again, right?

Comment: Have you defined your entries in the preamble or in the `document` environment? If you've defined them in the `document` environment then you need two LaTeX runs + `makeglossaries` + LaTeX before you see the effects of your changes as mentioned in the section [Drawbacks With Defining Entries in the Document Environment](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#sec:docdefs) of the user manual. If that doesn't fix it a MWE is required.

Comment: Move `\input{Inhalt/glossaries}` to the preamble, remove the `.glsdefs` file (if it exists) and retry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm new here, but as you only made a comments and no answer I have to answer my own question. It seems that is allowed :)

Nicola Talbot was right:

> Move \input{Inhalt/glossaries} to the preamble, remove the .glsdefs file (if it exists) and retry

Now if I change a glossary I don't even have to run "makeglossaries" again to make the change effective.

Thanks and Regards,
Lukas

Comment: Answering your own question is indeed allowed - even encouraged. When the answer comes from a comment you can either do what you did, thanking as you did, or ask the commenter to post her comment as an answer.

Comment: I had an error with entries occurring twice in the glossary, removing the `.glsdefs` files did the trick for me